# Is there a particular way to accept Theertha given at temples?

Tags: temple, rituals

When we go to temples, the purohit gives theertha which is the holy water to all the devotees. Is there a particular way to cup our hand to accept it? My grandpa believes there is a way where one must keep a cloth under the hand. I just wanted to know if there is a rule for this.

Comment: There is a mudra like bending your index finger to touch the base of your thumb.Similar mudras are employed by some while doing achamana.It is supposed to make your palms "pure"

Comment: this question is very similar - http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/795/what-is-the-significance-of-teertham-offered-to-devotees

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely. There is a particular way how to accept Theertha given in a temple or even while doing an achamana.

1. Firstly,while accepting the theertha, our palm should be folded in such a way that our index finger bends and the thumb bends over  index finger. By doing like that our middle finger slightly bends forward. This is the perfect position to take Theertha.
2. Then our right palm should be placed in our left palm both separated by a cloth.
   3.Some people sip the theertha from the palm. But theertha must be taken without making any sound and the lips should not be touched by the palm. If done so it is counted as a dosha **equivalent to drinking blood**.
3. After consuming theertha, some people rub their hands to their heads,stomach or to eyes saying that the theertha is auspicious.Doing so is not right. We should wash our hands. But there will be no time to wash our hands as the priest approaches us with the SHATHAGOPAM or SHATHAARI. Our hands should be wiped with a cloth and the cloth should be washed immediately after going home.
    A similar question was asked in an episode of a TV show called Dharmasandehalu on Bhakthi TV and was answered by Shree Kakunuri Suryanarayana garu a well known scholar in telugu states.
   For more clarifications, watch the full episode [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fJGft0Y2pM) if you can understand telugu.